# Servlet returning GIF image not animating

Tags: servlets, gif

First in my servlet I was using a Image-Servlet jar from some blog, my images were working fine. But the problem was any one can use inspect element and append the url with `../` to get to other directories also which was a big security problem. So I asked a question on SO, people suggested to make my own code as it was easy and I could have full control.

So here is my code,

```
    String path1=getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("");      
    System.out.println(path1);  // /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/myProject    
    String l = File.separator;

    f = new File(path1+l+"images"+l+"load.gif"); 
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bi, "gif", out);
    out.close();
```

It works good, but the problem is the image dont animate any more. I tried downloading it and opened it but it was not animating.

So I guess during reading the file into bufferedImage something changed.

the images looks like these 
[image: animating gif]
[image: non animating gif]
You can see in inspect element or source that both are gif but only one is animating

Answer (score 1):

You are just sending the first frame of the image.

ImageIO.read reads only the first frame (and a BufferedImage can only contain a single frame/image)

You can achieve it by the same technique used to send any binary content.

```
 String path1=getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("");      
 System.out.println(path1);  // /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/myProject    
 String l = File.separator;

 f = new File(path1+l+"images"+l+"load.gif"); 
 OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
 InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);

 try {
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
         int count;

         while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
           out.write(buffer, 0, count);
         }

// Flush out stream, to write any remaining buffered data
out.flush();
 }
finally {
in.close(); 
}


 out.close();
```

credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005750/why-is-my-gif-image-sent-from-servlet-not-animating)