# Why is my gif image sent from servlet not animating?

Tags: java, image, gif, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have this following code in my servlet

```
 response.setContentType("image/gif");
 String filepath = "PATH//TO//GIF.gif";
 OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
 File f = new File(filepath);
 BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
 ImageIO.write(bi, "gif", out);
 out.close();
```

This code is just returning first frame of the image.

How to achieve returning full GIF image ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your GIF does not animate, because you are sending only the first frame to the client. :-)

Actually, you are, because `ImageIO.read` reads only the first frame (and a `BufferedImage` can only contain a single frame/image). You are then writing that single frame to the servlet output stream, and the result will not animate (it should be possible to create animating GIFs using `ImageIO`, but the code to do so will be quite verbose, see [How to encode an animated GIF in Java, using ImageWriter and ImageIO?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8549460/1428606) and [Creating animated GIF with ImageIO?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/777947/1428606)).

The good news is, the solution is both simple, and will save you CPU cycles. There's no need to involve `ImageIO` here, if you just want to send an animated GIF that you have stored on disk. The same technique can be used to send any binary content, really.

Instead, simply do:

```
response.setContentType("image/gif");
String filepath = "PATH//TO//GIF.gif";
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
try {
    FileUtils.copy(in, out);
finally {
    in.close();
}

out.close();
```

`FileUtils.copy` can be implemented as:

```
public void copy(final InputStream in, final OutputStream out) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
    int count;

    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    // Flush out stream, to write any remaining buffered data
    out.flush();
}
```